# .htaccess is working fine on localhost but not on server?

Tags: .htaccess

This is pretty fine working on local server. But when upload on server this is not working.

```
RewriteRule ^activate_account/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ activate_account.php?activation_code=$1
```

Page working but passed argument doesn't get. [Live Demo](http://itbrainsteer.com/activate_account/Gajanand1337097636.html).

Comment: Try adding `Options -Multiviews`

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this updated code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^activate_account/([^.]+)\.html$ activate_account.php?activation_code=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check at first if AllowOverride is active for your hosting solution.
2. The next step is to check that the ModRewrite module is active.
3. You need the statement `RewriteEngine on` which should be active if that works on localhost